# Php specify type in phpdoc for ftp connection

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a property `protected $connection`. It is the result of `ftp_connect`. I want to add phpdoc for it. But I do not know its type. I tried to dump it and the result is `FTP buffer resource`. `gettype` result is just `resource`. Is there a way do document it?

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you tell what's wrong with the question. If you link me to resources then you should at least tell what's the problem. Otherwise your comment makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the type is `resource` it is [special php type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php).

The proper doc should be

```
/**
 *  @var resource
 */
```

You can find it as well on [phpdoc site with types](http://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/types.html#primitives)